# Getting link from pastebin and downloading from link

Tags: c#, download, pastebin

I'm trying to get a link from a pastebin. Where the link is the only text in the raw paste. Then I want to download a file from the link in pastebin.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://pastebin.com/raw/Dtdf2qMp");  

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();     

System.IO.StreamReader reader = new  

System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.DownloadFile (Link gotten from pastebin here, "c:\\File");

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dumping the text read to console output, you should assign it to a variable.

```
var pastebinOutput = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Then just pass that as the link for the DownloadFile method. If you want to do verification that it's actually a URL you got from the original pastebin, you can look into `System.Uri`'s TryCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution - assuming you have your link in the raw pastebin link (mine is a .txt file saying 'it worked') I suggest you copy and paste the code below exactly - if you get an file saying 'it worked' then you can change the pastebin link & file names. If you don't want to open the file then remove Process.Start - if you want to change the delay just change the number (it's in milliseconds) Also, you can change the format from .txt to .exe or whatever your file is (or you can remove it so its the defualt name in the download link):

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://pastebin.com/raw/QAWufg1z");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

System.IO.StreamReader reader = new

System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

var pastebinOutput = reader.ReadToEnd();

WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.DownloadFile(pastebinOutput, @".\downloaded.txt");
MessageBox.Show("File should open automatically in the next minute. Please wait...");
await Task.Delay(3000); //3000 = 3 seconds

Process.Start(@".\downloaded.txt");
```